# Unexplained Overfull Box

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I was trying to create a long horizontal bar where to put the marks of an assessment and I had created the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\TotalMarks}[1]{%
    \tikz\draw[thick]
    (0,0) -- (\linewidth,0) -- 
    ++(0,2em) -- ++(-2em,0) -- 
    ++(0,-2em) node[pos=0.6,left] 
        {\makebox[2.9cm]{\textbf{Total: #1 marks}\hfill}};}

\begin{document}
\TotalMarks{2}
\end{document}
```

I cannot understand why it gives an Overfull error:

```
Overfull \hbox (0.79999pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 14--15[][]
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you for any help you may give me.

Comment: It's because the `linewidth` try this: `\tikz\draw[thick](0,0) -- (\linewidth-21pt,0)`

Comment: @AndréC More about the paragraph indentation. `\noindent\tikz ..`

Comment: And don't use `minimal`. It's *not* for typesetting any type of document.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I realized it afterwards with the `showframe` package

Comment: Sorry, in the original document `parindent` is set to be equal 0pt. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: .8pt is twice the width of a rule, as the first comment suggests you can just reduce by the amount that tex told you is overfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that cause this:

1. Paragraph indentation. The standard paragraph indentation is added before the tikzpicture, you can disable that for a single line with `\noindent`, i.e. `\noindent\tikz...`
2. When you draw a line, the bounding box will actually extend by half the line width beyond the end coordinates, as you can see from this example:

   ```
    \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [line width=5mm] (0,0) -- (1,0);
      \draw [very thin, red] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5);

      \draw [thin, blue] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
   ```

[image]

The blue line indicates the bounding box.

If you add `line cap=rect`, the line will extend to fill that blank space, and you `pgf` has the handy macro `\pgflinewidth` that has the width of the current path. Hence, you can do `\draw[thick,line cap=rect] (0,0) -- (\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,0) ...`.

Working example, as egreg mentioned you shouldn't use `minimal` ([Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\TotalMarks}[1]{%
    \tikz\draw[thick,line cap=rect]
    (0,0) -- (\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,0) -- 
    ++(0,2em) -- ++(-2em,0) -- 
    ++(0,-2em) node[pos=0.6,left] 
        {\makebox[2.9cm]{\textbf{Total: #1 marks}\hfill}};}

\begin{document}
\noindent\TotalMarks{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment about the paragraph indentation before posting the answer, but point 2 covers the remaining 0.8pt.

Comment: This works brilliantly! Such a good explanation, thank you very much about it!